# How to change the textTheme of flutter app outside MateriapApp Buildcontext

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget, flutter-build

I created a class to make light and dark theme for my flutter app and for that I removed my previous theme and replaced it with the new class

**Previous MaterialApp**

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
    scaffoldMessengerKey: Utils.messengerKey,
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      dividerColor: Colors.black,
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
    ),
    home: MainPage(),
  );
}
```

**New MaterialApp**

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context)=> ThemeProvider(),
    builder: (context, _){
      final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
      return MaterialApp(
        scaffoldMessengerKey: Utils.messengerKey,
        navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,
        darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme,
        theme: MyThemes.lightTheme,
        home: MainPage(),
      );
    },
  );
}
```

**and finally this is MyThemes class and ThemeProvider**

```
class ThemeProvider extends ChangeNotifier{
 ThemeMode themeMode = ThemeMode.dark;

 bool get isDarkMode => themeMode == ThemeMode.dark;

 void toggleTheme(bool isOn){
   themeMode = isOn? ThemeMode.dark: ThemeMode.light;
   notifyListeners();
 }
}

class MyThemes{
 static final darkTheme = ThemeData(
   scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
   colorScheme:const ColorScheme.dark(),
 );

 static final lightTheme = ThemeData(
 scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
   colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(),
     dividerColor: Colors.black,
     textTheme: GoogleFonts.aguafinaScriptTextTheme(
       Theme.of(context).textTheme,
     ),

 );
}
```

So my problem starts here. I am getting the error

> Undefined name 'context'.

which make sense because I dont have a build context on this class and I cant figure out how to pass this text theme to the MaterialApp context

Comment: You can create and return a themedata without a context.  Then just consume that themedata in the right slots in your MaterialApp

Answer (score 1):

you need a context to a static method, i think you must changed into static function :

```
static lightTheme (BuildContext context) 
    => ThemeData(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(),
      dividerColor: Colors.black,
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.aguafinaScriptTextTheme(
        Theme.of(context).textTheme,
      ),
    );
```

it cannot be const right? because you need actual build context there;

Comment: Thanks for your response. This actually works but it will throw an error everytime I switch between dark and light theme.  ": Failed assertion: line 1085 pos 12: 'a == null || b == null || a.inherit == b.inherit': is not true."

Comment: what if remove `static`, and put in `materialApp`( ---> theme: `MyThemes.lightTheme(context),`

Comment: Then I will need to make a constructor of MyTheme class and even tho I did it the same problem occured

Comment: I tried to use Copywith but the same error is thrown:
 theme: MyThemes.lightTheme.copyWith(textTheme: GoogleFonts.aguafinaScriptTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,),
      ),

Comment: ah there is a 2 context, in your widget tree. maybe the class get the wrong context? try to change the name your child `context`

Comment: If thats the case then the font will not be changed but the thing is its working in all the cases but it just throw this error first and then reload the app with the new font

Comment: wait a minute, i will try the code of my self, you use a package flutter_provider right?

Comment: Yes. if you need any more details let me know

Comment: I think I solved it :). theme: MyThemes.lightTheme.copyWith(
         textTheme: GoogleFonts.aguafinaScriptTextTheme(
        ),), .... I just removed the line "Theme.of(context).textTheme," from CopyWith and it worked

Comment: nice, maybe you found what the cause is? post your own answer please so everybody who need it can see

Comment: I actually looked at the documentation from GoogleFonts and they had similar stuation on the examples they provided so with some modifications it worked! Anyway thank you for your help and I appreciate it

Comment: so its actually from another package like google_font? i cant reproduce it because not include it , glad to hear. happy coding

Comment: I dont think its because of the package cause even when I tried it without the google_font package the same issue happened but I inspired my answer from the example of this package

Answer (score 0):

For those who had similar issue, this is how I solved it:

```
return MaterialApp(
    scaffoldMessengerKey: Utils.messengerKey,
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    themeMode: themeProvider.themeMode,

    darkTheme: MyThemes.darkTheme.copyWith(
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
      colorScheme:const ColorScheme.dark(),
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(
      ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark).textTheme,
      ),),

    theme: MyThemes.lightTheme.copyWith(
      textTheme: GoogleFonts.openSansTextTheme(
        ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light).textTheme,

      ),),
```

I used Copywith method to add the font inside the MaterialApp and added the brightness theme inside google font to ensure the correct theme